# Sudoku Board Generator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, sudoku

I am working on a Sudoku board generator that generators a valid complete Sudoku board.


My algorithm generates a valid board, but the runtime is variable. Time varies from ~0.2 to 8 seconds. Ideally, I would like to get it to < 1 second consistently.


The logic part of the algorithm is what is taking the longest. It has to ensure each 3x3 square has unique numbers 1-9, and it has to ensure each column has unique numbers 1-9. If it does not, the algorithm randomly chooses another permutation to use and then tries again.


If someone could provide me with optimization tips, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
    NUM_ROWS = 9
    NUM_COLS = 9

    def fill_grid(grid):
        # get all permutations for 1-9
        all_permutes = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], r=9)) 

        # append one permutation to each row
        for i in range(NUM_ROWS):

            """
            get lists for all the columns and squares

            to help check for a valid board
            """
            # make each current column into list
            curr_col_set = []
            for j in range(NUM_COLS):
                col = []
                for k in range(NUM_ROWS):
                    col.append(grid[k][j])
                curr_col_set.append(col)

            # make each current square into list
            curr_square_set = []
            for j in range(0, NUM_ROWS, 3):
                for k in range(0, NUM_COLS, 3):
                    square = []
                    for l in range(j, j+3):
                        for m in range(k, k+3):
                            square.append(grid[m][l])
                    curr_square_set.append(square)

            """
            use logic to ensure each row results in valid board
            """
            allowed = False
            while not allowed:
                allowed = True
                choice = random.choice(all_permutes)
                for j in range(len(choice)):
                    if choice[j] not in set(curr_col_set[j]): # ensure digit isn't in col
                        if i < 3: # ensure digit isn't in square
                            if j < 3:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[0]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break
                            elif j < 6:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[3]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                      
                            elif j < 9:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[6]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                        
                        elif i < 6:
                            if j < 3:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[1]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                     
                            elif j < 6:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[4]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                        
                            elif j < 9:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[7]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                       
                        elif i < 9:
                            if j < 3:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[2]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                       
                            elif j < 6:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[5]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break                       
                            elif j < 9:
                                if choice[j] in curr_square_set[8]:
                                    allowed = False
                                    break


                    else:
                        allowed = False
                        break 


            all_permutes.remove(choice) # remove the row from all_permutes
            grid[i] = choice # add row to board

        return grid


grid = [[0 for i in range(NUM_COLS)] for i in range(NUM_ROWS)] # 9x9 grid of 0's
grid = fill_grid(grid)
```

Comment: You code is not formatted properly: `fill_grid()` seems to be indented when it should not be.  Also, you're missing imports.  I've edited the tags to say you are using Python; can you confirm it is Python-3.x?  Also, the title shouldn't say "Optimizing" because that is not what the code does; the title should describe the what the code does, not the goal of posting the question (everyone posting on Code Review wants code optimized, clarified, simplified etc; stating it is not helpful.)

Comment: I seem to recall that one valid board can be turned into other valid boards by swapping rows/cols within a set of 3, or by swapping a set of 3 rows/cols with another set of 3 rows/cols.  That might make a faster routine, or one that runs in a fixed time.

Comment: @RootTwo You would also need to add relabelling (permutations of the numbers).  However, I don’t believe this generates all possible solutions.

Comment: @AJNeufeld yes, it is Python3.x . Thank you for editing the question and tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Repeated `set()` construction

```
    allowed = False
    while not allowed:
        allowed = True
        choice = random.choice(all_permutes)
        for j in range(len(choice)):
            if choice[j] not in set(curr_col_set[j]): # ensure digit isn't in col
```

Consider the 7th, 8th or 9th row.  You are grabbing a random permutation, and checking to see if `choice[j]` is in `set(curr_col_set[j])` for each column `j`.  How many times is `set(curr_col_set[j])` being constructed?  Once for each random row permutation?

Maybe you could construct it exactly once:

```
    curr_col_set = []
    for j in range(NUM_COLS):
        col = set()                        # Set, instead of list
        for k in range(NUM_ROWS):
            col.add(grid[k][j])            # Set needs add instead of append
        curr_col_set.append(col)
```

And then you can remove the set construction out of this line:

```
            if choice[j] not in curr_col_set[j]: # ensure digit isn't in col
```

The code now runs a little faster.

Note that with list comprehension, we can reduce the code for the set generation, and speed it up slightly in the process:

```
    curr_col_set = []
    for j in range(NUM_COLS):
        col = set(grid[k][j] for k in range(NUM_ROWS))
        curr_col_set.append(col)
```

Or even further:

```
    curr_col_set = [set(grid[k][j] for k in range(NUM_ROWS)) for j in range(NUM_COLS)]
```

Do the equivalent to the `curr_square_set` to speed up the `choice[j] in curr_square_set[ ]` calls.

### Reducing the Search Space

When your algorithm starts, `all_permutes` has 362880 entries.  After you pick the first row, you remove that row, so the search space reduces by one, to 362879.  Not a huge reduction.

However, when you pick a row, that locks in digits which cannot appear again in those respective columns.  If you removed all rows where any digit matches a digit in the current `choice` selection, you'd significantly reduce the search space, and remove the possibility of randomly selecting those rows which can't possibly work.  Moreover, you wouldn't need to keep track of the `curr_col_set`, because you'd be guaranteed not to select a row where a duplicate digit appears in the column because those possibilities no longer exist.

So, remove the `curr_col_set` construction code, and the `if ...: else:` statement involving it, and replace:

```
    all_permutes.remove(choice) # remove the row from all_permutes
```

with:

```
    # Remove all row permutations where any column digit matches the current one.
    all_permutes = [ row for row in all_permutes if all(x != y for x, y in zip(row, choice))]
```

With this change, `all_permutes` drops from `362880` to `133496`, then to `43412`, then to `12040`, `2742`, `488`, `52`, `2`, and finally to `1` as the 9 rows are generated.